# What happens if booking.com doesn't have your credit card and the booking was cancelled?

Tags: bookings, hungary

So a couple of weeks ago i tried to book on booking.com for 3 nights in december, they called me to tell me i put november instead and i was supposed to check in today, i messed up the dates (my bad). Now i have to pay 50% of the reservation fee, but i made this booking without using my credit card (it said no credit card needed to finish booking). so what will happen if i just don't pay this fee?

how do hotels in Hungary enforce this kind of payment?
urgent replies are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happen but may you will receive a mail from the hotel that ask you 50% of the booking fee. Some hotel usually send mails and asking that, some other just delete your booking without asking you that fee.